# Disable SuSEfirewall2 on boot

Tags: iptables, sles

I am using an ancient version of SuSe (SuSe 10.2). I have turned off SuSEfirewall2 by running this command:

```
SuSEfirewall2 stop
```

That definitely stopped iptables. Is there a way to disable iptables on boot so I don't run into this issue again?

Comment: You can delete thensusefirewall script from the init directors

Comment: You mind providing steps on where to go to delete it? I am not too familiar with out SLES is set up..

Comment: I don't have a system here, just search it: `ls /etc/init.d/*firewall* /etc/rc*/*firewall* /etc/init.d/rc*/*firewall*`

Comment: So looks like it is in the rc.d directory which runs scripts on startup... So deleting the SuSEfirewall_init and setup script should fix this, no?

Comment: Yes, at least the links Named S* in rc*.d

Comment: cool i moved em to /root for now.. i wish i can reboot it to test but i cant at the moment

Comment: @eckes You might as well post an answer suggesting that, it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For init.d style systems (like old SUSE) it is normally enough to remove all start (`S*firewall`) scripts from all `/etc/rcX.d/` directories.